# How to add sum values of array according to keys in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of php like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Sr_No] => 1
            [Asan_Category] => Warm-Up
            [Asan_Cat_Val] => 8
            [Asan_Sub_Category] => Ankle
            [Asan_Sub_Cat_Val] => 35
            [Asan_Name] => General Ankle Warm up
            [Asan_Name_Val] => 447
            [Prescribed_Steps] => 40
            [Prescribed_Ratio] => 00
            [Actual_Steps] => 12
            [Actual_Ratio] => 0
        )
 [1] => Array
        (
            [Sr_No] => 2
            [Asan_Category] => Warm-Up
            [Asan_Cat_Val] => 8
            [Asan_Sub_Category] => Knee
            [Asan_Sub_Cat_Val] => 111
            [Asan_Name] => General knee warm up
            [Asan_Name_Val] => 464
            [Prescribed_Steps] => 20
            [Prescribed_Ratio] => 00
            [Actual_Steps] => 14
            [Actual_Ratio] => 0
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [Sr_No] => 1
            [Asan_Category] => Warm-Up
            [Asan_Cat_Val] => 8
            [Asan_Sub_Category] => Ankle
            [Asan_Sub_Cat_Val] => 35
            [Asan_Name] => General Ankle Warm up
            [Asan_Name_Val] => 447
            [Prescribed_Steps] => 40
            [Prescribed_Ratio] => 00
            [Actual_Steps] => 10
            [Actual_Ratio] => 0
        )
[3] => Array
        (
            [Sr_No] => 2
            [Asan_Category] => Warm-Up
            [Asan_Cat_Val] => 8
            [Asan_Sub_Category] => Knee
            [Asan_Sub_Cat_Val] => 111
            [Asan_Name] => General knee warm up
            [Asan_Name_Val] => 464
            [Prescribed_Steps] => 20
            [Prescribed_Ratio] => 00
            [Actual_Steps] => 9
            [Actual_Ratio] => 0
        )
)

The desired output I want 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Asan_Id] => 447
            [Asan_Category] => Warm-Up
            [Asan_Sub_Category] => Ankle
            [Asan_Name] => General Ankle Warm up
            [Prescribed_Steps] => 40
            [Prescribed_Ratio] => 00
            [Total_Steps] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Asan_Id] => 464
            [Asan_Category] => Warm-Up
            [Asan_Sub_Category] => Knee
            [Asan_Name] => General knee warm up
            [Prescribed_Steps] => 20
            [Prescribed_Ratio] => 00
            [Total_Steps] => 23
        )
)
```

I want those data who are repeating become one but their different actual steps become total steps with their sum.
Please help me because I have tried some code but did not success like this

```
    $asan=[];
    $total_steps=0;
    foreach ($aasan_details as $key) {

        $total_steps += $key['Actual_Steps'];
        if(!in_array($key['Asan_Name_Val'],$asan))
        {
            $asan[] = $key['Asan_Name_Val'];

          $lookup[] = array("Asan_Id"=>$key['Asan_Name_Val'],
                      "Asan_Category"=>$key['Asan_Category'],
                      "Asan_Sub_Category"=>$key['Asan_Sub_Category'],
                      "Asan_Name"=>$key['Asan_Name'],
                      "Prescribed_Steps"=>$key['Prescribed_Steps'],
                      "Prescribed_Ratio"=>$key['Prescribed_Ratio'],
                      'Total_Steps'=>$total_steps);
        }


    }
```

It is not working , what should I do guys , please help me out

where `$aasan_details` is the array which I showed above and the in lookup array I am getting uniqe values but not getting  their total

Comment: Excuse me, but total steps contains the sum by id..

Comment: Can you provide a `var_export` output of the dummy data?

Comment: Asan Id is the asan name val

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to move this into a database and use a query to perform that exact operation for you.

But if you have to do it in code, you could use a keyed array to basically group them up by however many fields need to match for them to be conjoined:

e.g.

```
foreach ..
$consolidated[$item['Asan_Cat_Val']][$item['Asan_Sub_Cat_Val']][] = $item;
```

Then make a couple of nested loops to go across this and sum everything up.

Answer (score 0):

There a few useful techniques to explain here...

1. You can reduce eye-strain in your looped array declarations by establishing a collection of keys that you know you want to retain in (copy to) the output array.  This spares you having to type out each `$keyName => $row[$keyName],` like [this](https://3v4l.org/pka9P) (but ultimately make yourself happy).
2. Declare temporary associative keys (using `$id`) while building your output array to allow `isset()` to make super fast checks for a pre-existing group.
3. If a group is not yet set, then store the data with the new keys along with the data with the original keys.  No arithmetic is necessary.  The `+` symbols in my snippet are not "addition operators", they are "array union operators" -- they are merging the three arrays without a function call (otherwise `array_merge()` would do the same).
4. When finished iterating the array, you may choose to re-index the result (remove the temporary associative keys) by calling `array_values()`.  If you are not bothered by the existence of these temporary keys, you can omit the function call.
5. If a group has been encountered before, you only need to modify the `Total_steps`.  Use  an addition-assignment operator (`+=`) for the briefest syntax.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GAQZJ))

```
$keysToKeep = array_flip(['Asan_Category', 'Asan_Sub_Category', 'Asan_Name', 'Prescribed_Steps', 'Prescribed_Ratio']);

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $id = $row['Asan_Name_Val'];
    if (!isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id] = ['Asan_Id' => $id] + array_intersect_key($row, $keysToKeep) + ['Total_Steps' => $row['Actual_Steps']];
    } else {
        $result[$id]['Total_Steps'] += $row['Actual_Steps'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Asan_Id' => '447',
    'Asan_Category' => 'Warm-Up',
    'Asan_Sub_Category' => 'Ankle',
    'Asan_Name' => 'General Ankle Warm up',
    'Prescribed_Steps' => '40',
    'Prescribed_Ratio' => '00',
    'Total_Steps' => 22,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Asan_Id' => '464',
    'Asan_Category' => 'Warm-Up',
    'Asan_Sub_Category' => 'Knee',
    'Asan_Name' => 'General knee warm up',
    'Prescribed_Steps' => '20',
    'Prescribed_Ratio' => '00',
    'Total_Steps' => 23,
  ),
)
```

Comment: @satya You have asked a couple of php question, now, that have included sample input arrays.  Please always provide your sample array data as `var_export()` output or as a json string.  This way volunteers don't have to toil with converting your data into a code-ready structure.